# cannot run program CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python-3.x

Error running 'main'
Cannot run program "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\snake-game\venv\Scripts\python.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\snake-game"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

running a python snake game program